# Symfony project - Doctrine Self-Reference issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relationship, one-to-many, self-reference

I am working on a Symfony 6.1 project and have the following situation. I have an entity called "MaterialGroup". A material group can be in a parent-child relation with itself so one material group can have some "subGroups" and one subGroup can only belong to one "upperGroup". So basically it is ay One-to-Many Relationship.

Now, when I want to update the relations in the "new" or "edit" function of the controller in symfony it basically does not work. I do not get any errors and the if I use the function "dd()" in order to preview the parent materialGroup, I can see the subGroups that should be mapped. However after the flush nothing happens.

Here is my current code:

**Entity**

```
class MaterialGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=MaterialGroup::class, inversedBy="subGroups")
     */
    private $parentMaterialGroup;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MaterialGroup::class, mappedBy="parentMaterialGroup")
     */
    private $subGroups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subGroups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getParentMaterialGroup(): ?self
    {
        return $this->parentMaterialGroup;
    }

    public function setParentMaterialGroup(?self $parentMaterialGroup): self
    {
        $this->parentMaterialGroup = $parentMaterialGroup;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection<int, self>
     */
    public function getSubGroups(): Collection
    {
        return $this->subGroups;
    }

    public function addSubGroup(self $subGroup): self
    {
        if (!$this->subGroups->contains($subGroup)) {
            $this->subGroups[] = $subGroup;
            $subGroup->setParentMaterialGroup($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSubGroup(self $subGroup): self
    {
        if ($this->subGroups->removeElement($subGroup)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($subGroup->getParentMaterialGroup() === $this) {
                $subGroup->setParentMaterialGroup(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }  
}
```

**Edit function in Controller**

```
    #[Route('/{id}/edit', name: 'edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, MaterialGroup $materialGroup, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(MaterialGroupType::class, $materialGroup);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $request->request->all();

            $subGroups = [];
            if(isset($data["material_group"]["subGroups"]))
                $subGroups = $data["material_group"]["subGroups"];

            //Get the material group objects for all the subGroups
            $requestSubGroups = [];
            foreach($subGroups as $value) {
                $requestSubGroups[] = $this->materialGroupRepository->find($value);
            }

            //"Insert" the new subGroup relations
            foreach($requestSubGroups as $subGroup) {
               $materialGroup->addSubGroup($subGroup);
            }

            //This dd() leads to the object you can see after the code for the edit function in this post
            dd($materialGroup);
            
            $this->entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute($this->routeName.'_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm($this->routeName.'/edit.html.twig', [
            $this->routeName => $materialGroup,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

This object shows the subGroups that should be mapped to this materialGroup before the flush. And after the flush they are not mapped:

```
App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1116 ▼
  -id: 982
  -parentMaterialGroup: null
  -subGroups: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1324 ▼
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1335 ▼
      -elements: array:5 [▼
        0 => App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1707 ▶}
        1 => App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1729 ▶}
        2 => App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1750 ▶}
        3 => App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1771 ▶}
        4 => App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1885 ▶}
      ]
    }
    #initialized: true
    -snapshot: array:4 [ …4]
    -owner: App\Entity\Tables\MaterialGroup {#1116}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager {#452 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "parentMaterialGroup"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#1009 …}
    -isDirty: true
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am misunderstanding or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

tried setParentMaterialGroup function instead of addSubGroup after getting the subGroup:

```
$subGroup->setParentMaterialGroup($materialGroup);
```

Comment: Yes, this may work, but why can't I use the subGroup functions, such as "addSubGroup" here, for this? In the end, in addSubGroup() for each subGroup also "setParentMaterialGroup()" is executed.

Comment: yes even in the addSubGroup function it calls the setParentMaterialGroup function, you are modifying the entities that will have a parent, it is the id of the parent entity that will be stored in the child entity, usually the add function works for me, you have to see the symfony profiler and follow the logs and see what it does when you flush

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone tell me what I am misunderstanding or doing wrong here?

this is:

> A material group can be in a parent-child relation with itself

If u want relations u should create different entities for set relations between them.

Comment: It is actually a mapping. You can find it in the docs of doctrine under "One-To-Many, Self-referencing": https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing